# How to filter dataframe based on condition that index is between date intervals?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, time-series

I have 2 dataframes:
df_dec_light and df_rally.

```
df_dec_light.head():
    log_return  month   year
1970-12-01  0.003092    12  1970
1970-12-02  0.011481    12  1970
1970-12-03  0.004736    12  1970
1970-12-04  0.006279    12  1970
1970-12-07  0.005351    12  1970
1970-12-08  -0.005239   12  1970
1970-12-09  0.000782    12  1970
1970-12-10  0.004235    12  1970
1970-12-11  0.003774    12  1970
1970-12-14  -0.005109   12  1970
```

```
df_rally.head():

rally_start rally_end
0   1970-12-18  1970-12-31
1   1971-12-17  1971-12-31
2   1972-12-15  1972-12-29
3   1973-12-21  1973-12-31
4   1974-12-20  1974-12-31
```

I need to filter df_dec_light based on condition that df_dec_light.index is between values of columns df_rally['rally_start']and df_rally['rally_end'].

I've tried something like this:
`df_dec_light[(df_dec_light.index >= df_rally['rally_start']) & (df_dec_light.index <= df_rally['rally_end'])]`

I was expecting to to recieve filtered  df_dec_light dataframe with indexes that are within intervals between df_rally['rally_start'] and df_rally['rally_end'].
Something like this:

```
    log_return  month   year
1970-12-18  0.001997    12  1970
1970-12-21  -0.003108   12  1970
1970-12-22  0.001111    12  1970
1970-12-23  0.000666    12  1970
1970-12-24  0.005644    12  1970
1970-12-28  0.005283    12  1970
1970-12-29  0.010810    12  1970
1970-12-30  0.002061    12  1970
1970-12-31  -0.001301   12  1970
```

Would really apreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Provide sample dataframes as text and expected output dataframe

Comment: @RomanNedev do you want to the df_dec_light result to be included as long as it is in any of the rally date ranges?

Comment: @thomas Yes, correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this we can first turn the ranges in `df_rally` into `pd.DateTimeIndex` by calling `pd.date_range` on each row. This will give us each row of `df_rally` as a `pd.DateTimeIndex`. 
As we want to later check if the index of `df_dec_light` is in any of the ranges, we want to combine all of these ranges. This is done with `union`. 
We assert that the newly created `pd.Series` `index_list` is not empty and then select its first element. This element is the `pd.DateTimeIndex` on which we can now call `union` with all other `pd.DateTimeIndex`. 
We can now use `pd.Index.isin` to create a boolean array of whether each index Date is found in the passed set of Dates.

If we now apply this mask to `df_dec_light` it returns only the entries that are within one of the specified ranges of `df_rally`.

```
index_list = df_rally.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['rally_start'], x['rally_end']), axis=1)
assert(not index_list.empty)
all_ranges=index_list.iloc[0]
for range in index_list:
    all_ranges=all_ranges.union(range)
print(all_ranges)
mask = df_dec_light.index.isin(all_ranges)
print(df_dec_light[mask])
```

Comment: thank you for you help! I've just made some addition with ```all_ranges = all_ranges.date```.(otherwise it was showing error:"FutureWarning: Comparison of Timestamp with datetime.date is deprecated in order to match the standard library behavior. In a future version these will be considered non-comparable. Use 'ts == pd.Timestamp(date)' or 'ts.date() == date' instead.")  Once again - much appreciated for your time and help!

Answer (score 2):

Let's create an `IntervalIndex` from the start and end column values in `df_rally` dataframe, then `map` the intervals on index of `df_dec_light` dataframe and use `notna` to check if the index values are contained in any interval

```
ix = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df_rally.rally_start, df_rally.rally_end, closed='both')
mask = df_dec_light.index.map(ix.to_series()).notna()
```

then use the `mask` to filter the dataframe

```
df_dec_light[mask]
```